# Physical keyboard layout on macbooks

Tags: macbook-pro

Is there a way through command line to know what keyboard physical layout a macbook has? I cannot find that specific information in system_profiler. I want to know if the computer has a US, UK, ES, etc keyboard layout. The aim is to script it, upload it to my MDM so I can run it in all the company's laptops and find out that information.

Running the terminal command `system_profiler SPSPIDataType` it shows this:

```
SPI:

Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad:

  Product ID: 0x0278
  Vendor ID: 0x05ac (Apple Inc.)
  ST Version: 8.96
  MT Version: 4.69
  Serial Number: FM7741701QVGN41A5+RNZ
  Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
  Location ID: 0x01000000
```

I run it in two different macbooks, one UK, one ES. I was hoping that the Location ID would show something different but that was not the case.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or ask for your question to be migrated - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57295133/get-physical-keyboard-layout

Comment: Be nice if you could post the answer you posted there for the benefit of users here...

Comment: What actually *is* the physical layout, which specific values would be possible results?

Answer (score 2):

I think I just found the solution, like this:

```
ioreg -l | grep KeyboardLanguage | awk '{print substr( $0, 56, 20)}' | tr -d "\" =|"
```

Comment: Running `ioreg -l | grep KeyboardLanguage` returns `      | | | |   |   |   |   "KeyboardLanguage" = "Swiss Multilingual Keyboard"` here, so assuming a fixed field length in `awk` is not enough: `ioreg -l | grep KeyboardLanguage | cut -d\" -f 4`

Comment: Also this doesn't seem to return the actual keyboard layout...

Comment: Why not? is that the input souce, then?

Comment: If you just need it as part of an asset catalogue it's probably enough :-)

Comment: Well I formatted a macbook with a physical british kb. During the installation the input source was spanish-iso. On the first keyboard assistant I chose spanish-iso input source. Then I run the command and I get "british". So I conclude that's reflecting the actual physical layout... but I might be wrong.

Comment: Physical layout is not the same as input source. Physical is, well, physical (what type of keyboard, which letters are printed where), input source is which keys are interpreted as which letters. So I can have a swiss keyboard layout but an US input source for instance.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. So what I'm chasing is a way to find out the physical one other than looking at the computer itself or its box. A way to script that. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a good thing to have.  On my iMac with a US keyboard it doesn't seem to produce any result however.

Comment: I don't have an iMac to test it. But for sure its keyboard is external usb, so we'll have to search somewhere else.